# Get earliest Y-m-d date value in a multidimensional array from qualifying rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, min, date-comparison

I want to get the minimum date from the date column of a multidimensional array, but only from rows with `keycode` of `0001`.

How would I achieve that?

```
$a = [
  "a" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-09-08"],
  "b" => ['keycode' => '0002','date' => "2015-09-05"],
  "c" => ['keycode' => '0003','date' => "2015-09-04"],
  "d" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-09-01"],
  "e" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-08-01"]
];
```

Expected result: `2015-08-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first extract all of the values that have a keycode of 0001 and create a new array of just those dates. Then use the php `min()` function.

[PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bd2fae0f72ecb7c12b995489fadb59b859702de)

```
$a=array(
  "a" => array('keycode' => '0001','date' =>"2015-09-08"),
  "b" => array('keycode' => '0002','date' =>"2015-09-05"),
  "c" => array('keycode' => '0003','date' =>"2015-09-04"),
  "d" => array('keycode' => '0001','date' =>"2015-09-01"),
  "e" => array('keycode' => '0001','date' =>"2015-08-01")
);

$b = [];

foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if($value['keycode']=='0001'){
     $b[]=$value['date'];
    }
}

print_r($b);

echo min($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function min_date($a){
 $dates = [];
 foreach($a as $key => $value){
 if($value['keycode']=='0001'){
    array_push($dates,strtotime($value['date']));
  }
 }
 return date("Y/m/d",min($dates));
}

$result = min_date($a);
```

Comment: thank you your answer was the second closest to what i needed sir. I do not need to convert the date format but hopefully soon i could use this answer of yours in a project where i might need it thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
function getMinDateByKeycode(array $a, $keycode)
{
    // Filter out elements by keycode
    $aFiltered = array_filter($a, function($aItem) use ($keycode) {
        return $aItem['keycode'] === $keycode;
    });

    // Sort lowest date first
    uasort($aFiltered, function($a1, $a2){
        return strtotime($a1['date']) - strtotime($a2['date']);
    });

    // Get the key of the first element of the resulting array
    reset($aFiltered);
    $keyOfMinDate = key($aFiltered);

    // Return it however you want. This example returns just the date.
    return $a[$keyOfMinDate]['date'];
}

echo getMinDateByKeycode($a, '0001');
// prints '2015-08-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is already sorted and you are using php 5.5.0+, then you can try this

```
$arr = array_column($a, "date", "keycode");
echo $arr["0001"] // string(10) "2015-08-01"
```

Comment: This answer only works by happenstance.  [Watch it fail when the input data is different.](https://3v4l.org/dWntS)  Using `array_column()` in this way just keeps overwriting subsequent values when a duplicate key is encountered.  In other words, you always get the last occuring date for the `0001` key.

Answer (score 0):

Because your date expression are already in `Y-m-d`, they are instantly comparable as simple strings.  This means that there is no need to call `strtotime()` for any part of this task.

If you prefer `usort()`, you can sort on two criteria.  The following snippet will first sort on the `keycode` and put all `0001` rows at the front and everything else toward the back of the array.  When a tiebreak is required, the second sorting rule is to compare the dates ASC.

When finished, the first occurring row will either be the `0001` row with the smallest date value or it won't be a `0001` row because there weren't any in the input array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uqrri))

```
$array = [
  "a" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-09-08"],
  "b" => ['keycode' => '0002','date' => "2015-09-05"],
  "c" => ['keycode' => '0003','date' => "2002-12-04"],
  "d" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-09-01"],
  "e" => ['keycode' => '0001','date' => "2015-10-01"]
];

$needle = '0001';

usort($array, fn($a, $b) => [$a['keycode'] !== $needle, $a['date']] <=> [$b['keycode'] !== $needle, $b['date']]);

echo $array[0]['keycode'] === $needle ? $array[0]['date'] : "No qualifying rows for $needle";
// 2015-09-01
```

---

If you'd rather see a classic loop, then this approach will conditionally update a temporary variable. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/umaP9))

```
$needle = '0001';

$earliest = null;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row['keycode'] === $needle && (!$earliest || $row['date'] < $earliest)) {
        $earliest = $row['date'];
    }
}
echo $earliest ?? "No qualifying rows for $needle"; // 2015-09-01
```